# Adding text to a combobox

Tags: vba

Currently I have a simple ComboBox that populates with 3 items when clicked:

```
        With FunctionBox
            .AddItem "Add Blank Issue"
            .AddItem "Move Existing Issue"
            .AddItem "Reorder Issues"
        End With
```

However, the combobox is empty before the dropdown arrow is selected.

When the combobox appears I want it to show something like, "Please select one of the options below".

I tried setting the 'Value' of the combobox to 'test'.  Test shows up in the editor, but does not when I run the application.

I also want to make sure the string goes away when the down arrow is selected and the user cannot interact with it.

Any advice?

I can provide screenshots if this is somewhat unclear.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't show up, I just tested here, and entering text into "TEXT" or "VALUE" property in design mode, then save, and it shows up fine when "running".  Have you changed any other options when creating? Are you using a FORM combo box, or ActiveX combo box ? Try creating a new combo box, set the property "ListFillRange" to a range in the sheet and populate your list there (instead of via vba code like you did) . does that change the behavior at all ?

Comment: I see what happened.  I changed the FunctionBox.Style to fmStyleDropDownList.  I did this to prevent users from accidentally typing in the combobox, resulting in an error.

I wonder if there is a way to have that style of box, but still be able to have an initial flavor text.

Answer (score 0):

Goto design view of your form, click on the combo box in question and change the text value to what you want it to say.

Edit - didnt see the 2nd part of your question

put this in the dropbuttonclick event. changing combobox1 where needed

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
ComboBox1.value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: I did do that and I can see the text in my combobox on my userform when I'm in the visual basic editor.  However, when I run the application it does not show.  Perhaps I'm hiding it somewhere, I'll look into it real quick.

Comment: Start a blank form just add 2 comboboxs and see if it is working that way, if you can not find what is causing it. Worked fine for me on a new form

Answer (score 0):

To have a default value in combobox, add this code in UserForm_Initialize():

```
FunctionBox.AddItem "Please select one of the options below"
```